# Do Young Earth Creationists believe that insects, microorganisms, and animal cells died before the Fall?

Tags: young-earth-creation, fall-of-man, animals

As explained in answers to other questions,<sup>1 2</sup> young-earth creationists (YECs) believe that there was no *animal* death prior to the Fall.  They accept that plants must have "died," since man and now-carnivorous mammals were then herbivores ([Genesis 2:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis+2%3A16&version=ESV)).

Besides plants, do YECs believe that anything else died before the fall?  Examples that come to mind are insects, microorganisms, and animal cells (such as human skin cells).

Is there general agreement among YECs as to where to draw the line? On what basis do they draw it?

---

<sup>1</sup> [Before the fall of Adam, did anything die?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/12076/21576)
 
<sup>2</sup> [Does the Bible say if animals in Eden were carnivorous, or when animals on Earth became carnivorous?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/31722/21576)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This article on the Answers In Genesis website is a good introduction:

https://answersingenesis.org/death-before-sin/did-death-of-any-kind-exist-before-the-fall/

One short quote:

> The Bible never uses the Hebrew term *nephesh chayyah* (living soul/creature) when referring to invertebrates, but it does when referring to humans and fish (Genesis 1:20; 2:7). Also, insects do not have the same sort of “blood” that vertebrates do, yet “the life of the flesh is in the blood” (Leviticus 17:11) (Sarfati 2004, p. 211). It is reasonable then to assume that the pre-Fall diet of animals could have included invertebrates.

Thus the distinction is between creatures with a certain kind of blood and the breath of life and those that do not. Creatures that lacked the breath of life and blood were subject to death, but that death has no spiritual component and is not the sort of death ushered in by the fall.

UPDATE:
As to the second question about whether God created carnivores, I know of no scriptural evidence, but there is anecdotal evidence that carnivores can live on fruits and vegetables. Here are two articles, one about a lion that refused to eat meat and lived a long, healthy life, and the other about how crocodiles love to eat fruit.

https://answersingenesis.org/reptiles/fruit-eating-crocodiles-dispel-carnivorous-misconceptions/

http://creation.com/the-lion-that-wouldnt-eat-meat

Comment: Very interesting update!  But actually, with the 1 & 2, I was just referencing previous questions and answers -- you answered my question very nicely with your original post.