# Did GOD create pathogens after the sin of Adam and Eve?

Tags: genesis

Did GOD create pathogens after the sin or fall of Adam and Eve?

Comment: Welcome Justin. Many Christians believe in "old-earth creationism," which will have a very different answer to this question than "young-earth creationists." Our goal here is to objectively describe and learn what specific groups of Christians believe, so if you tell us whose opinion you want, we can answer this question.  When you get a chance, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Related: [Do Young Earth Creationists believe that insects, microorganisms, and animal cells died before the Fall?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/41714/21576)

Comment: He didn't have to create it necessarily. Everything could have been set up this way already and if the sin enters the world all becomes distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of possible ways to look at this.

First, we know that God finished creation according to Genesis. That is to say that He did not continue inventing new life forms and physical structures. When man sinned a fundamental change occured in not only his relationship with God but also with creation. Carnivores became a danger and quite possibly micro-organisms became a problem due to Adam and Eves fallen state. The glory of God that once clothed their nakedness may have been the very thing that empowered their immune system to fight all foreign organisms in their system. Being that immunity and antibodies are a highly integrated system generated in the bone marrow, one would have to conclude this was part of Gods original design of man.

Another way to view it is that after the curse brought on creation by sin, some things changed and took on more dangerous properties through mutation. This is not a nod towards the notion of evolution but simply a acknowledgement that there are variations in genetic coding over time. The scripture does indicate that when Adam and Eve were cast from the garden that the ground would produce thorns for them. This could be a general metaphor regarding the natural and biological threats that would arise in the world around them.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing.  Unfortunately, the question you've answered is not particularly good for our format in its current state, since it invites answers from many different perspectives.  As a result, it will likely soon be closed. I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: I think thats an unfortunate decision. I understand many issues in academia and science have objective sets of facts and stack exchange is particularly designed to deal in such facts. But the sheer attempt to provide a format for questions regarding the Christian faith while at the same time setting such rigourous standards for what is allowed to be asked or answered runs counter to the exploratory, intuitive and even inspired nature of faith discussions. I believe I understand the question perfectly. Why not wait to see if the questioner confirms that I have before assessing it as too vague?